# how to filter the fields of a document within another document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

My document is the following

```
{

 "name":"Name1",
  "status":"active",
  "points":[
   {
      "lag":"final"
   },
   {
      "lag":"final"
   }
   
  ]
},
{

 "name":"Name2",
 "status":"active",
  "points":[
   {
      "lag":"final"
   },
   {
      "lag":""
   }
   
  ]
}
```

I need to get all the documents that have some value in the lag field, for this example should get two document,
I tried with this query, but it only returns me when all points have full lag

```
{ "points.lag":{$not:{ $eq:"" }},status:{$in:['active']}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RHm8R3VV0bm)

You need to use `elemMatch` to check whether atleast one element matches the condition.

```
db.collection.find({
  "points": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "lag": {
        $ne: null
      }
    }
  }
})
```